# Plone 4 : Sorting and Pagination

Tags: python, sorting, macros, pagination, plone

I'm displaying a table of records in a page. Say the records are about 200, and I have enabled pagination to 30 rows a page. I have also enabled sorting using the method discussed [here](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/making-tables-sortable/usage).

The pagination works fine, but when I sort a column, it only sorts the current page and not all the records i.e. the current 30 rows instead of 200.

Does this feature exist in Plone 4 where one can sort all the pages in a table?

Below is a sample of the code that I have:

```
<div metal:use-macro="here/batch_macros/macros/navigation" />
<table class="listing" id="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Table header</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div metal:use-macro="here/batch_macros/macros/navigation" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try ExtJS listing AJAX widget if you need advanced sorting. Warning: it will be much more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the column sorting is uber-simplistic, i.e. it just sorts whatever you have in the column alphabetically. So no, without writing it yourself you won't be able to update your batches. Doing so, should not prove to be too hard though.